# Poisson Distribution fit

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, distribution, curve-fitting

i need to fit a Poisson distribution to a set of data:

```
fitfunc = lambda p, x: p[0]*pow(p[1],x)*pow(e,-p[1])/math.gamma(x+1) # Target function
errfunc = lambda p, x, y: fitfunc(p, x) - y # Distance to the target function
p0 = [1., 2.] # Initial guess for the parameters
p1, success = optimize.leastsq(errfunc, p0[:], args=(bins_mean, n))
```

I made that using the example given in the [SciPy documentation](http://wiki.scipy.org/Cookbook/FittingData).

If I comment the gamma function part, it works like a charm, so the problem is there, but I have no clue on how to solve it.

I get the following error:

```
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "int") to list
```

The input arguments of the fit are the output of plt.hist, i checked and the type is numpy ndarray

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: There is no need for optimization here if you have the data (not just a histogram).  For a poisson distribution, you can analytically find the best fit parameter (lambda, your `p[1]`) just by taking `np.mean(data)`.  `p[0]` is just normalization.

Comment: Are `bins_mean` and `n` numpy arrays? The error leads me to believe that you are passing lists.

Comment: Yes, i know that, but i need to make the fit to automatically to automatize a program with varying data, and also i need to fit the same data to a bose distribution for compare.

Comment: @Jasimud, If I'm not mistaken, the fit can be done "automatically" just fine: `p = data.size, data.mean()`

Answer (score 4):

```
fitfunc = lambda p, x: p[0]*pow(p[1],x)*pow(e,-p[1])/math.gamma(x+1) # Target function
errfunc = lambda p, x, y: fitfunc(p, x) - y # Distance to the target function
p0 = [1., 2.] # Initial guess for the parameters
p1, success = optimize.leastsq(errfunc, p0[:], args=(bins_mean, n))
```

Since you say that it works without the math.gamma(x+1) part, i am guessing that it will work if you change

```
fitfunc = lambda p, x: p[0]*pow(p[1],x)*pow(e,-p[1])/math.gamma(x+1)
```

to

```
from scipy.misc import factorial 
fitfunc = lambda p, x: p[0]*pow(p[1],x)*pow(e,-p[1])/factorial(x)
```

since math.gamma doesnt like lists (or anything that aint a float  i guess), while factorial can work properly with lists?

Side question: why do you use pow, instead of just using ** ?